# Using Calibre, figuring out RegEx expressions. Configuring metadata from file name

Tags: regex, filenames, calibre

I am trying to use Calibre on my mac to organize my ebook library.

As a summer personal project, I created various epubs of my nephews' and nieces' school reports as keepsakes on my computer and phone. I had labeled the files as: Title_Last Name, First Name.epub

For example: Report on ATP Cycle_Doe, John.epub

With Calibre I found you can configure metadata from the file name: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrMON.jpg)

For example:

```
(?P<title>.+) - (?P<author>[^_]+)
```

Would only work if the file name was: Title - First Name Last Name.epub

I tried:

```
(?P<title>.+)[^\w](?P<author>[^_]+)
```

And it would return the title as: Report on ATP Cycle Doe,
And the author as: John

Can anyone can help me figure out a RegEx expression to extract the title and author from the file name convention that I used?

Such that the title is: Report on ATP Cycle
And the author is: John Doe

It is much appreciated.

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/lP2hO0/6 ? Second group contains last name and the third group contains first name.

Comment: Hi, I used your expression but I believe Calibre requires the <author> syntax for identifying the author's name:  
  
[Image](http://imgur.com/CPgSmLa)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^(?P<title>[^_]+)_(?P<author>.*)\.epub$
```

In the **[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cX0zG2/1)**, look at the named groups in the right pane.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?P<title>[^_]+)` captures chars that are not an underscore to the `title` capture group
- `(?P<author>.*)` captures any chars to the `author` capture group
- `\.epub` matches `.epub`
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Variation**

If for some reason the regex is not supposed to match the `.epub` extension, use this instead:

```
^(?P<title>[^_]+)_(?P<author>[.^]+)
```

Comment: I used the above expression but Calibre did not read the syntax for the author:  
  
[First expression](http://imgur.com/SxXU2fE)  
  
[Second expression](http://imgur.com/7enpo2l)  
  
Can you offer another solution? I also appreciate your help and explanation in clarifying the syntax. Thank you.